# read excel worksheets and data

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datareader

I want to read to my WEBApplication excel file,
I found a way to do it with connection string the problem is that i don't spouse to know the work sheet amount and names. moreover, i want to use this names in DropDownList to give the user the ability to choose one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If in your project you set a reference to assembly `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` you can read your Excel file and use all functions you need.

**EDITED after user comment**:

```
public void Read(string filename)
{
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);

    // Get worksheet names
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sh in wb.Worksheets)
        Debug.WriteLine(sh.Name);

    // Get values from sheets SH1 and SH3 (in my file)
    object val1 = wb.Sheets["SH1"].Cells[1, "A"].Value2;
    object val3 = wb.Sheets["SH3"].Cells[1, "A"].Value2;
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", val1, val3);

    wb.Close();
    excel.Quit();
}
```

Comment: I've tried too, couldn't fine exactly what i need, can you give an example similar to my question please?

Comment: Get Excel File, get the names of all worksheets, and specific cell of one of them

Comment: "getting this error after file upload: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file .... -  " There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook."

Comment: @ItayM: did you check that excel file exists in the place you're searching it? If my code works for a template file, you should check what your web app is doing...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the OLE DB provider for Jet.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175866.aspx